# RaiseEvent PreviewMouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf

How does one go about raising an event for PreviewMouseDown. I can successfully do this for MouseClick events... but falling short on the preview variation. The goal is the automate PreviewMouseDown and then PreviewMouseUp only when needed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "automate PreviewMouseDown" but PreviewXXX routed events in WPF are tunneled down the control automatically (from top of the visual tree) and then it calls the XXX event which gets bubbled up.

There is no way you can 'just' call PreviewXX event. Though you can handle them separtely by attaching to the right event.